# Displaying data of 1 column in multiple lines

Tags: excel

I got a C++ program that does some processing and save the results in a csv file, I want the data are integer values that are saved in 1 column. To mark that I'm in a new messurment I add an empty row ,
my question is how can I tell excel to plot  a new line in the diagram  if it finds a an empty row ?
to explain what I want to do here is  an  example  :

[image: what I get]

[image: what I want]

By the way  I can't save the  data of the new messurement in a a new column because I'll other data in colmuns!

any idea hwo to solve this ?
thanks in advance !

Comment: Looks like you will need a VBA script to make process this column and break it into separate columns. Or maybe you should make changes to your program that makes the CSV so that series of data go horizontally?

Comment: is there anything that I can set as an end of line in a column ?

Comment: Nope, I don't think this can be achieved using formulae alone. To transform the data you'll need VBA. I see this like copying values one by one until empty cell is encountered. Then switching destination to a new column an continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula. `*7` is the quantity of numbers in a column (6) + space (1).

[image]

Comment: what if the quantity of numbers is different ?

Comment: You mean it can vary? Then this solution won't work.